# Why is hpa scaling in the wrong direction?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

I have two Horizontal Pod Autoscalers, for different deployments with *identical* metric value and target, and they are scaling in *opposite* directions. The condition of one ("dev") is `ScalingLimited: TooFewReplicas` and the condition of another ("stable") is `ScalingLimited: TooManyReplicas`!?

```
$ kubectl get hpa
NAME         REFERENCE               TARGETS               MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
ows-dev      Deployment/ows-dev      399m/700m, 83m/750m   20        40        20         13d
ows-pyspy    Deployment/ows-pyspy    400m/700m, 83m/750m   1         2         2          2d16h
ows-stable   Deployment/ows-stable   399m/700m, 83m/750m   2         5         5          44h
other        Deployment/other        232m/150m             2         6         6          8d
```

How can we debug what the `hpa` is doing? (My guess is that we've unintentionally configured multiple deployments with a metric query that picks up all of those deployments collectively, and it looks like the API is reporting on that value averaged over *all* resources but perhaps internally the `hpa` is only averaging within each deployment, and hence working from a different value than reported?)

`describe` doesn't give very much more detail:

```
$ kubectl describe hpa/ows-dev
...
Metrics:                         ( current / target )
  "flask_http_request" on pods:  401m / 700m
  resource cpu on pods:          88m / 750m
Min replicas:                    20
Max replicas:                    40
Deployment pods:                 20 current / 20 desired
Conditions:
  Type            Status  Reason               Message
  ----            ------  ------               -------
  AbleToScale     True    ScaleDownStabilized  recent recommendations were higher than current one, applying the highest recent recommendation
  ScalingActive   True    ValidMetricFound     the HPA was able to successfully calculate a replica count from pods metric flask_http_request
  ScalingLimited  True    TooFewReplicas       the desired replica count is less than the minimum replica count
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age                From                       Message
  ----    ------             ----               ----                       -------
  Normal  SuccessfulRescale  21m (x2 over 20h)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 21; reason: pods metric flask_http_request above target
  Normal  SuccessfulRescale  21m (x2 over 20h)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 22; reason: pods metric flask_http_request above target
  Normal  SuccessfulRescale  20m                horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 23; reason: pods metric flask_http_request above target
  Normal  SuccessfulRescale  19m                horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 24; reason: pods metric flask_http_request above target
  Normal  SuccessfulRescale  14m (x2 over 24h)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 22; reason: All metrics below target
  Normal  SuccessfulRescale  13m (x4 over 21h)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 21; reason: All metrics below target
  Normal  SuccessfulRescale  11m (x5 over 22h)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 20; reason: All metrics below target
```